# Add events to svg string in component and render it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, frontend

Basically what I need is to add event listeners to particular elements in my svg, that I receive as in param in my component

```js
export default function RoomPlan({ svg, startDate, endDate}) {
  const [selectedDesk, setSelectedDesk] = useState(null);
  const [previouslySelectedDesk, setPreviouslySelectedDesk] = useState(null);

  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg, "text/xml");

  var elements = Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll('#desk rect'));

  if (elements) {
    elements.forEach(function (el) {
      el.addEventListener("click", function(){alert('hi')});
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className={css.labels}>Select desk</h2>
      <div id={css.roomPlan} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc)}}></div>
      <div className={css.bookingButtons}>
        <Button id={css.cancelButton}>CANCEL</Button>
        <Button onclick={bookDesk(selectedDesk)}>BOOK DESK</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I get it as a plain string then parse it to DOM then add my eventListeners and serialize it back. But with this approach the ivents are not presented and do not trigger. So question is: how I can make it work as intendet with string -> DOM -> addedEvents -> render the svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only attach event handlers after react rendered the markup into the DOM. For this to work you might look up [react ref with callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node).

```
const ref = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      /* do your magic here: node.querySelectorAll('#desk rect') ... */
    }
  }, []);


<div id={css.roomPlan} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svg}} ref={ref}></div>
```